# Winforms app shows this error when running: Root element is missing

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I have a Winforms application developed in C# that works in a PC but it does not in other. In the other, the error "root element is missing" is shown according to this call stack:

[image]

I check the app.config file and it has no problem. Furthermore, this application works in the other PC. I suspect there is an issue with the operating system installation but which one (this is windows 10 with all updates installed).

What may be happening here?

By the way, in the call stack, the top most call is the most recent one, right?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: The error message and stack trace by itself isn't enough information to help you. Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: How did the app get onto the "other" PC. Did you [Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/deploy-modern-applications) it with an .msi, .msix or similar package? Or are you trying to copy the executable files?

Comment: @gunr2171 there is no reproducible example. As I have told, applications works in other PC's but not in this PC which is brand new. My hope is that someone tells me that there is a magic operating system patch that solves the problem or that for some reason the machine.config file in the PC got corrupted. Some errors I have encountered before have this kind of solutions, for example, some configuration errors in IIS are solved by re-registering ASP.NET with IIS. In this case it is a Winforms so maybe someone has faced this error before and can give me a clue.

Comment: @IVSoftware it is an installer (MSI) I have used everywhere. I have used the same installer in the failing PC but that error occurs.